# Adding a new column to a FITS file via python

Tags: python, fits, pyfits

I have created an array named **distance** that contains 1242 values. I want to add this array as the 11th column in an already existing FITS file that contains 10 columns.

I am using pyfits.

I tried pyfits.append(filename, distance) which showed no errors but did not add my column to the FITS file.

Any suggestions??

Comment: Are you trying to add a column to a table?  `pyfits.append` just appends an array as a new IMAGE HDU.

Comment: Yes, I would like to add a column to a table. How can I do that? @Iguananaut

Comment: Does it need to use pyfits?  Otherwise I would s/python/PyFITS in the title :)

Comment: Please can you explain your previous comment. If there is any other way of adding the column to the fits file, please let me know.

Comment: Have you seen http://pyfits.readthedocs.org/en/v3.2.0/users_guide/users_table.html#merging-tables ?

Comment: @Iguananaut that is exactly what I am doing at the moment. but I want to add my new column/list to an existing FITS table. The problem with the current method in my case is, I need to create a new FITS with just the list i created and then merge that table with the existing table.

Comment: You can use a simplified version of that example without creating a new file.  The way the columns are combined is by adding two [ColDefs](http://pyfits.readthedocs.org/en/v3.2.0/api_docs/api_tables.html#pyfits.ColDefs) lists.  You can just create a `ColDefs` containing a single [Column](http://pyfits.readthedocs.org/en/v3.2.0/api_docs/api_tables.html#pyfits.Column) including the column data array and add those.  You still need to write it to a new file.  Adding columns to a FITS table is tricky since they are row-oriented and it requires moving all the rows around.

Comment: It so happens I'm actually in the process right now of updating the PyFITS docs, so I've added a new example motivated by this question.  See the second example here: https://github.com/embray/PyFITS/blob/f18853addec03cbae5b9db27653dcff15b687ec5/docs/source/users_guide/users_table.rst#merging-tables

Comment: In the linked example, do you create a new fits file where to merge the new table?

Comment: @Py-ser In the linked example, a new FITS file is created wherein the new columns are appended. But yes, a new table needs to be created! I couldn't find a way to append a column and update an existing FITS

Comment: @Iguananaut I am trying what you said from your website. I am using Python 2.6.6 and in
hdu = pyfits.BinTableHDU.from_columns(orig_cols + new_cols) 
I am not having the option from_columns

Comment: @srivatsan Sorry about that; the examples there are for the development version of PyFITS.  The equivalent example for older versions would by `pyfits.new_table(orig_cols + new_cols)`.  Give that a go.

Comment: Thanks both. But still no way to add a column within an already existing FITS file, right?

Comment: @Iguananaut, 'raise TypeError('Wrong type of input.')'

Comment: @Iguananaut, what about if I still receive this error `File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyfits-3.2.4-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/pyfits/column.py", line 1023, in __add__
    raise TypeError('Wrong type of input.')
TypeError: Wrong type of input.`

Comment: I don't know. I'd need to see more code--that seems to suggest that some of the arrays you're trying to add are not compatible with FITS but it's really hard to tell.

Answer (score 0):

Finally they released an updated library that allows the modification of a table extension in a human way!

Last release of [FITSIO](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/fitsio/). You can easily add a column with a code looking like the following:

```
import fitsio
from fitsio import FITS,FITSHDR
...
fits = FITS('file.fits','rw')
fits[-1].insert_column(name = 'newcolumn', data = mydata)      # add the extra column
fits.close()
```